# Extract key:value pair from an object sent to backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, backend

I am trying to use the value from an object. I don't need to use the 'key' part of the object. Also, I need to remove the curly brackets { } from around the object. How can I do so ?

I'm making a searchbar that sends data into backend, but I only need to use the 'value' part of the object. Perhaps I should use query strings for that ?

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault() // stop page from refresh

    if (setUserInput !== '') { // is searchbar isnt empty, then run the POST method to send 
// data from {userInput} which is the searchbar
      
      const options = 
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type':  'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({userInput}),
      };
  
      const response = fetch('http://localhost:3001/search', options);
      console.log("search entered");
    };

      }
```

in the backend when I console.log the response it gives me

```
`"{ userInput: 'lollol' }"
```

and out of all of that I only need the 'lollol' part  ( lollol is just an example, but whatever is typed into the searchbar will be shown instead of it ). As such:

```
const searchResult = req.body /// return lollol ✅
```

not

```
const searchResult = req.body /// return `"{ userInput: 'lollol' }" ❌
```

Should I use query strings to accomplish this, or is there a way to extract data from an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to stringify the object in the body. Replace

```
body: JSON.stringify({userInput}),
```

with

```
body: {userInput:userInput},
```

And then you can use it like `req.body.userInput`.
Hope, it helps!!

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I really liked that idea - however it's throwing a 500 (Internal server error) saying that userInput is not defined on the ```req.body.userInput``` server side. That was quite a simple yet thoughtful suggestion. I then removed userInput and now I'm receiving undefined data. Perhaps I need to use some middleware?

Comment: Ok, I figiured it out:
```
//To parse URL encoded data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

//To parse json data
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

The middleware was missing.
Thank you !!!

Comment: OMG THANKS SO MUCH!!! IT TOOK ME ABOUT A MONTH TO FIGURE THIS OUT - I LOVE YOU, THANK YOU